# DataGridview Skip The Value Of First Row Column

Tags: c#

The dataGridview **first row column** name **amount** is return no value as there is value inserted.

**For our Peers' Convenient I draw the table as it's help to answer it better.**

my table on dataGridview is as below:

```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("name",typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("amount",typeof(decimal));
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "f2";
    }
```

Now I prepared the table and my main code is below:

```
  private void dataGridView1_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        decimal sum = 0.00m;

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++) 
        {
                sum = sum + Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1[1, i].Value);
                textBox1.Text = sum.ToString("f2");
        }
    }
```

The above code throw Error like **"Object Cannot cast from DBNull to other types".** Even though there is value.

Now Look at to another Code:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        decimal sum = 0.00m;

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++) 
        {
            if (dataGridView1[1, i].Value != DBNull.Value) 
            {
                sum = sum + Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1[1, i].Value);
                textBox1.Text = sum.ToString("f2");

            }        

        }
    }
```

Now this code not throwing any Error but still the problem with it. The problem is when i enter the value on column of **amount** is look like it skip the value of first row's column name **amount**.

**e.g....**

I enter the value on column name **amount** is below:

```
1st Row column amount values is = 12
2nd Row column amount values is = 12
3rd Row column amount values is = 12
```

Now the total showing in textbox1 is = 24, where as actual total is = 36.

There is going something wrong with coding it shows that dataGridview's first row's column value is not accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Best Solution is as below:**

```
  private void dataGridView1_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        decimal sum = 0.00m;

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView1[1, i].Value != DBNull.Value)
            {
                sum = sum + Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1[1, i].Value);
                textBox1.Text = sum.ToString("f2");

            }

        }
    }
```

**Just Change The dataGridView Event as above.**

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataGridView1_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        decimal sum = 0.00m;

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++) 
        {
            if (dataGridView1[1, i].Value != DBNull.Value) 
            {
                sum = sum + Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1[1, i].Value);
                textBox1.Text = sum.ToString("f2");

            }        

        }
    }
```

the change is in the condition in the for loop.When your loop condition is i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1. You loop all the rows except the last one this is why you get 24 instead 36
Best Regards,
Iordan

Comment: @lordan, it's not works, it's return first rows column value is 0.00 you can try it.

Comment: @lordan, You are wright but try it. it's return only. 0.00 in textbox1 where i enter the value "12" on dgv first rows' column.

Comment: @mahesh is it possible to put this peace of code in some other even because if you are editing the value of the cell the new value may not be put in the Cell Value i will recommend putting this code in the CellEndEdit event